# Why my images in drawable not recognized in layout-land?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, screen-orientation

I am making android learning example. It is about the screen orientation.
I create **layout-land.xml** for landscape mode. The view displayed as expected in the landscape mode (reading from layout-land.xml not from layout.xml) ***except that the imageViews are not recognizing the images in drawable directory.***

I tried to create a folder drawable-land and put my images in it, but this didn't work?

***layout-land.xml:***

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context=".MainActivity"
   android:orientation="vertical">
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/screen_type_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:textColor="#06b800"
    android:text="It's Land Scape !"
    />

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/android_apple"
    />
```

Any idea please?

Comment: "except that the imageViews are not recognizing the images in drawable directory" -- what does this mean?

Comment: Do you have this picture `android_apple` in your drawable folder?

Comment: yes I have this *android_apple* in both drawable and drawable-land

Comment: ImageView is reading the image source in layout.xml but not in layout-land.xml

Comment: `layout-land.xml ` what is this? you are supposed to have an xml file with the same name in the `layout-land` folder. `layout-land.xml ` does not make sense

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android studio, creating a new drawable folder does not work.Upload your picture to the default drawable folder.

Comment: also check your Linear layout tag is not closed.

Comment: My picture already exist in the drawable folder but it is not loaded from the layout-land.xml .

Comment: @chang As @njzk2 told you: `layout-land.xml` will be not recognized as a valid layout file.